# pre-requisite for connection pooling

Tags: c#

What is a pre-requisite for connection pooling?

Thank you.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. This question is not answerable as written.

Comment: Having some connections is a prerequisite. Otherwise your pool will be empty. Why do you want to know?

Comment: What kind of pre-requisite? What type of connection are we considering?

Comment: More context please. Or the question will be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean database connections, the main points are:

- they must all use **exactly** the same connection string
- it is per-AppDomain
- for SSPI etc, the implicit user account must be common (i.e. the same domain user is being represented, or it will form multiple pools)
- it must be enabled and supported by the provider; in the case of `SqlConnection` it is on by default
- you must have not explicitly disabled the pool

For most common cases using `SqlConnection`, this just means "will be pooled per unique connection-string" - the rest is automatic and *just works*.

also; remember to use `using` statements around your connection usage, so you release things back to the pool even in exception - otherwise you'll exhaust it.

Comment: Have you read the article I am refering to in my answer? The first question/statement about the connectionstring is quite interesting.

Comment: @Erno - shuffling the parameters isn't a very helpful case, of course...

Answer (score 0):

[A very interesting article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/connection_pooling_myths_p1.aspx) although I am not entirely sure whether or not it is still valid.